# Should we separate the [the-dark-eye] tag into multiple tags for multiple versions of the game?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are multiple editions of the game "The Dark Eye" - 5 of them, to be exact. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Eye#Game_history), 2 of them have (official) English translations, though TDE 4/4.1 had only a very small number of its books ever translated.

The problem: We currently only have the tag [the-dark-eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye), encompassing (theoretically) all the editions. This leads to problems that can, for example, be seen in [this answer to the question "How many skill points should I give my players for winning an encounter?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/170987/18056). Theoretically, the answer is right - for TDE4/4.1 - but it is wrong for TDE5. And the question itself does not clarify which version the op is playing. (Well, we could guess, and it would probably be accurate, but we can not know for sure - and as per our policy, we should not guess)

There are currently 36 questions with the tag. I would guess that most of them are for TDE5, but that is solely based on the assumptions that most German players of TDE simply use the official (German) game forums for questions and stuff like that. But I don't think we would be able to correctly tag the questions (I could tag my question about TDE, and Trish is also still around, but there are old questions in the tag that are not from me or Trish but from people who do not seem to be around any longer, so....)

What should we do about this situation? I have to admit that I am not that active here any more (I'm more of a silent reader for the last year(s)), so I am not exactly sure what the right way forward would be.

Comment: makes sense to me, but as I don't play I don't feel qualified to answer

Comment: That's the thing: I don't think there are that many people that play it and look at meta :D

Comment: Self-correction: 10... and sorted all questions.

Comment: Related: [Do we need a separate tag for Numenera Discovery?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9942/do-we-need-a-separate-tag-for-numenera-discovery), [Do we need more Mutants and masterminds edition tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/do-we-need-more-mutants-and-masterminds-edition-tags), [WFRP by Edition tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/wfrp-by-edition-tags), [Convention for sub-tags within a game system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/convention-for-sub-tags-within-a-game-system)

Comment: @V2Blast Can we put a status complete on this?

Comment: @Patta Can you accept as we went through all the stuff and retagged as appropriate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## This is just the fact-gathering and question sorting, not a statement for or against the question itself. It is for the reference of those that don't know the system.

First of all, a correction: there are technically **10** distinct editions, and I am using the German nomenclature here:

- **DSA 1** - 1984
- **DSA 2** - 1988
- **DSA 3** - 1992
- **Myranor Box** (*DSA 3.5*) - 2000 - somewhat of a proto-DSA-4 in many regards
- **DSA 4** *boxes* - 2001
- **DSA 4.1** *books* - 2006 - some dozen, at times large, rule changes. 4 and 4.1 characters and adventures are not slot-in replaceable and need to be re-calculated from the ground up!
- Myranor Hardcover  AKA **Myranor HC** - 2006 - The whole Myranor series uses at times large variations of the 4.1 rules, especially when it comes to magic.
- **DSA 5** - 2015
- **DSA-LARP** - 2018 - Spinoff
- **DSK** - 2019 - "Die Schwarze Katze/The Black Cat" - simplified offshoot of DSA 5

Of these, there are English variants of DSA 4, 4.1, Myranor Hardcovers, and DSA 5.

## Setting vs. System?

DSA has 3 main settings with multiple publications:

- **Aventuria**, the *central* continent of Dere. It is featured since DSA1 as the mainline place.
- **Tharun**, the hollow world *inside* the of Dere. It was a staple of DSA1 and 2 for high-level play. There was a re-release of the setting in DSA 4/4.1 but also a declaration that there won't be further new adventures in this place.
- **Myranor**, the *western* continent of Dere. Its books are rather distinct from the Aventuria ones and it uses standalone rules.

There had been plans to make content for the *eastern* continent **Riesland** and it is not clear if there is or isn't the *southern* continent **Uthuria** but so far there is not a lot content on either of these two.

All of the settings are set up in a complex sphere system, where the 1st sphere is creation as it is, 2nd has pure elements, Dere is the 3rd Sphere with Tharun and other alternate worlds being *Globules* on the same *height*, 4th being the afterlife, 5th being the realm of gods, 6th the firmament and the 7th sphere the ice-cold demon-lands of *Niederhöllen*. Between these spheres are inter-sphere realms. A fan-illustration with the German terms can be found [here](https://www.deviantart.com/erlkoenig/art/Spaehrenkarte-DSA-796406083).

## Question lineup

There are [currently](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye) 36 questions about TDE as a whole. And most are distinctively **not** TDE5: there's 10 TDE5, 11(12) TDE4/4.1. 6 unknown edition, 7 group related ones, 5 setting related ones.

### DSA 5

Retagging done!

- [How can I balance high-impact characters with "simpler" characters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109099/how-can-i-balance-high-impact-characters-with-simpler-characters) (via comment)
- [How do I subtly convey that the PCs’ reality is fake?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157945/how-do-i-subtly-convey-that-the-pcs-reality-is-fake) (via comment)
- [How can I run a large battle in The Dark Eye?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96694/how-can-i-run-a-large-battle-in-the-dark-eye) (via comment)
- [How to help a player choosing the right character-class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70707/how-to-help-a-player-choosing-the-right-character-class) (indicated in comment)
- [How many skill points should I give my players for winning an encounter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151152/how-many-skill-points-should-i-give-my-players-for-winning-an-encounter)
- [Is this Tiredness Effect balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93950/is-this-tiredness-effect-balanced)
- [Cannot find Wood Harness reference](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125132/cannot-find-wood-harness-reference) (via the book named, 4/4.1 used "Aventurisches Arsenal", 3 "Kaiser Retho's Waffenkammer")
- [Where to Find the Level 1 Focus Rules for Hit Locations](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101800/where-to-find-the-level-1-focus-rules-for-hit-locations) (while mentioning the Bestiary, which is a 4/4.1 book it's clearly aiming for the 5th edition from the Level Focus and PRO)
- [How to handle social skills in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102173/how-to-handle-social-skills-in-combat) (mentioned!)
- [How to deal with rumors](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95166/how-to-deal-with-rumors) (mentioned)

### DSA 3 or 4.1

not retagged

- [Players Characters don't meet the fundamental requirements for campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89301/players-characters-dont-meet-the-fundamental-requirements-for-campaign) - The campaign is clearly the Borbarad campaign (largest campaign ever) and that was published only for 3 and 4.1

### DSA 4 AND 4.1

Retagged

- [What are the main differences between version 4.0 and 4.1 of The Dark Eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25413/what-are-the-main-differences-between-version-4-0-and-4-1-of-the-dark-eye) Version Dispute

### DSA 4 or 4.1

- <del>[Which systems use character development mechanics similar to The Dark Eye?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/which-systems-use-character-development-mechanics-similar-to-the-dark-eye) (from the Level-less and 2012, more likely 4.1 which almost removed the last remnants of level but from one single rule (learning new skills))</del> (closed and need not get a new tag)

### DSA 4.1

retagged

- [The Dark Eye Universe: maximum plausible value of abilities for new character](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/the-dark-eye-universe-maximum-plausible-value-of-abilities-for-new-character) (mentioned)
- [Do benefits from a talent on a given spell only apply during character creation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63371/do-benefits-from-a-talent-on-a-given-spell-only-apply-during-character-creation) (mentioned in comment)
- [What counts as "sunlight" for the Albino and Fear of Light weaknesses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63249/what-counts-as-sunlight-for-the-albino-and-fear-of-light-weaknesses) (mentioned)
- [Number of actions to access equipment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73688/number-of-actions-to-access-equipment) (mentioned)
- [When do I announce my parry?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55690/when-do-i-announce-my-parry) (mentioned)
- [How to give the players more felt impact on the "Battle of the Silkwiesen"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109417/how-to-give-the-players-more-felt-impact-on-the-battle-of-the-silkwiesen) (4.1 is the Edition used, though the adventure itself was the DSA 4 re-release of a DSA 3 one...)

### Unknown edition (possibly DSA 4, 4.1 or 5)

Via date this might be 5 as well as 4 or 4.1:

- [Introducing Players to The Dark Eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93879/introducing-players-to-the-dark-eye)

From Date I suspect this is a 4 or 4.1, but dungeon sprawling was mostly a 1 to early 3 thing:

- <del>https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34719/recommend-large-complex-logical-dungeons</del> (locked and need not get a new tag)

### Edition agnostic

#### Player Group

- [How to stop players from trying to gauge success of meta-ideas via meta questions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115415/how-to-stop-players-from-trying-to-gauge-success-of-meta-ideas-via-meta-question) (though it's 4.1)
- [Make NPC death most dramatic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99122/make-npc-death-most-dramatic)
- [How to deal with a player that interrupts play?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109472/how-to-deal-with-a-player-that-interrupts-play) (though it's 4.1)
- [How to deal with a player "teleporting" to the action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123202/how-to-deal-with-a-player-teleporting-to-the-action) (though it's 4.1)
- [How can I convey to my group that they have to discipline their murderhobo?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145254/how-can-i-convey-to-my-group-that-they-have-to-discipline-their-murderhobo)
- [Dealing with leaving players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/dealing-with-leaving-players)
- [How to deal with players who take up most of the time by doing solo actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138098/how-to-deal-with-players-who-take-up-most-of-the-time-by-doing-solo-actions)

#### Setting

- [Koschbasalt / Blaubasalt vs. Magic Traps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/koschbasalt-blaubasalt-vs-magic-traps)
- [(How) can the Nameless One interact or interfere with mortals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95827/how-can-the-nameless-one-interact-or-interfere-with-mortals) (answer based on 5)
- [Is there a given fixed constellation starting point for various astrological bodies to calculate their position from for any day?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123563/is-there-a-given-fixed-constellation-starting-point-for-various-astrological-bod)
- [How to create a Sci Fi antagonist in fantasy RPG?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152629/how-to-create-a-sci-fi-antagonist-in-fantasy-rpg)
- [What is the life expectancy of different Races?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103591/what-is-the-life-expectancy-of-different-races) (though asked for DSA5)

### Homebrew with unknown edition as base

- [How can I communicate to my players, that I like them to roleplay their skills more?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140463/how-can-i-communicate-to-my-players-that-i-like-them-to-roleplay-their-skills-m)
- [How can I make a smart character act smart without prohibiting less intelligent characters from participating as well?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139439/how-can-i-make-a-smart-character-act-smart-without-prohibiting-less-intelligent)
- [How can I help my players to better immerse into my game world?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152821/how-can-i-help-my-players-to-better-immerse-into-my-game-world)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about separating 4 and 4.1 already, but decided not too simply because Wikipedia did not do it either (and I honestly don't know if it's worth it to differentiate them via tags...)

Comment: @Patta it's virtually impossible to sieve 4 and 4.1 from one another unless mentioned!

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I made some edits based on comment responses I got asking people to clarify their system.

Comment: I'm unsure exactly how you were counting the "unknown edition" in the section where you enumerate the editions and break down the difference. It's not a huge deal, but those numbers are likely off now from me moving some stuff around.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose unknown edition was the unknown+homebrew: current count: 9(+2) 5e, 9(+3) 4e, 3+3 unknown (+unknown homebrew), 7(-3) group, 5(-2) Setting

Answer (score 7):

As I sorted through the questions to the best of my knowledge, I think a distinction is needed:

- [the-dark-eye-4-4.1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye-4-4.1) as a joint 4/4.1 it's rather hard to sieve the 4 from the 4.1, plus the unknown recommendation one
- [the-dark-eye-5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye-5) for the 5
- [the-dark-eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye) for the unsortable and setting questions; possibly separate out the Player group ones where we know.

If the switch goes through, I suggest to close for clarity-needed (edition needed):

- <del>https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157945/how-do-i-subtly-convey-that-the-pcs-reality-is-fake</del> 5th
- <del>https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109099/how-can-i-balance-high-impact-characters-with-simpler-characters</del> 5th
- [Introducing Players to The Dark Eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93879/introducing-players-to-the-dark-eye)

Comment: I think it would be better to historical lock those than close them, since they are upvoted and were good at the time and such, and since it's not like we want them edited to include a system tag at this point-- we only let the OPs do that. +1 otherwise, though.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Our only option for locking that would be relevant here is a historical lock which tells people the question is also off topic, i.e. things like it should not be asked here. That would send very much the wrong message. On the other hand, closing saying we need more detail implies exactly what it ought to. We can close questions even when they're upvoted or when they didn't have issues identified previously.

Comment: I wonder whether the last tag should be [the-dark-eye-unknown-edition] or something, which might put people off using it without relying on the "DO NOT USE THIS" description that new users might not think to look at (this is assuming that was the intention behind that tag's new role should we split it up). Just calling it [the-dark-eye] might cause the same problems that we sometimes see with D&D where new users may use the [dungeons-and-dragons] tag when they're only asking about the specific edition they're playing because they don't know they should have used the [dnd-5e] tag instead...

Comment: I think it's a matter of "can this question be correctly answered without knowing the edition?". If it can, that might be justification for a general "multiple/all editions" tag (or a setting tag or whatever - I'm not familiar with the game and haven't checked which questions are about what). If it's a question that doesn't have a clear answer without knowing the edition (i.e. if determining the correct answer requires knowing the edition), it should be closed if the edition can't be determined. ...Basically, what doppelgreener said :P

Comment: @V2Blast The standard setting of TDE "Aventuria" is extremely entwined with the basic rules, while the "Myranor" setting has its own rule books that have different magic and priest mechanic. The Tharun setting was exclusive to TDE1&TDE2 and a single modern reprint that used the 4/4.1 rules without alterations. Yep, that's the exhaustive list of settings there are. Myranor, Aventuria, Tharun. Though the Aenturia setting does include various planes and some alternate worlds...

Comment: I think [the-dark-eye-4] would be more than sufficient, the natural assumption would be that point release would fold into it.