# Should we remove the [mutants-and-masterminds] tag from questions about a specific edition?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

This is a follow-up from [Fixing umbrella tag of mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12056/10867). There are currently 51 questions tagged with [mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds). Only 9 of them don't also have a [mutants-and-masterminds-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds-2e) or  [mutants-and-masterminds-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds-3e) tag. Since [mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds) is already implied for the two versions we have tags for (there's only a handful of identified 1E questions), it feels odd, inefficient I guess, to have it there so often when it really adds nothing to the classification of the questions. So, I asked advice on how to clean them up, and upon getting a suggestion of doing 5 each day (to avoid hogging the front page, I did so, only to find that I'd skipped a step of asking whether the group wants this change.

I'm not naïve enough to think that *Mutants and Masterminds* is much of a big deal here, so on one hand, this change doesn't do much to improve the site. On the other hand, it's also so small that this isn't much disruption. We've already split out tags for [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) and [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness), but some like [shadowrun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun) don't really encourage people not to put on the umbrella tag.

FWIW, each edition has been different enough that answers for one seldom help much with the others, except perhaps passing on historical answers (2E had many more questions answered for it by Steve Kenson, the game designer, where they declined to provide those explanations in 3E).

Comment: "I'm not naïve enough to think that Mutants and Masterminds is much of a big deal here" Smaller systems are important and should be handled with the same level of care, nay, greater care, than popular systems. Echoing doppel's comment from your last post, we want to be careful not to smuggle in our assumptions about what is best for popular systems to our discussions about smaller systems.

Comment: In contrast to some, I believe that we should even cater **more** to the smaller systems than just the latest big system.

Comment: @Trish: I have gotten a lot of mileage from compiling official errata answers for [tag:planet-mercenary] from the developer.

Answer (score 3):

### Keep it so I can follow just one tag

I'm given to think the editions aren't a million miles apart from each other.

Unlike [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) and [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)/[dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e) etc, there isn't an overarching franchise to worry about.

Comment: oh, there's also a benefit: it can put M&M to the front of the crawler-sort.

Comment: I'm going to give this a little more time to see if there's discussion, but I may just go with this. :-P Still feels excessive to me, but I can go with it. Next question, does it make sense to "fix" this on past and future questions?

Comment: You're the person who has shown the most interest in this. I'm going to start adding [tag:mutants-and-masterminds] to the ones that only have an edition tag.

Comment: @SeanDuggan only as your come across them

Comment: Ah. Fair enough. :-D

Answer (score 1):

### If we don't know the edition, keep the tag.

It's easy. we know the system, but not the edition - then we need to keep the system until such a time we can get a system added. See also [the-dark-eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye) where we did exactly that [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10021/30306)

If the edition is **relevant**: Vote to Close in addition.

### If it is lore questions, keep the tag.

If you are asking lore, then the tag is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: If we don't know the edition and it's an edition dependent question then it should be closed for "needs details".

Comment: That is a different problem though